# How to use journalctl with custom log file

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

I would like to make a backup of journal log files from a different machine and analyze them locally (while the other machine will get reformatted).

How can I:

1. Create a full backup of journal logs file (wherever it is).
2. Use journalctl with that copied file instead with default os log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [`journalctl` man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html), journal files are kept under `/var/log/journal` (for persistent logs) and `/run/journal` (for ephemeral logs).

The same document also describes the [`--file` option](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html#--file=GLOB):

> --file=GLOB
>
> Takes a file glob as an argument. If specified, journalctl will operate on
> the specified journal files matching GLOB instead of the default runtime and
> system journal paths. May be specified multiple times, in which case files
> will be suitably interleaved.

So you should be able to copy the journal files from other systems to a local directory, and then read them use the `--file` option to `journalctl`.

Comment: `--file` did not work for me giving me error `Failed to open files: No such device`, but following the path you mentioned I found that there is also `--directory` and that one worked fine.